# Canvas Data to Image Element

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I want to create a canvas element and put an image inside.
Before that I want to drawn anything in canvas em get back the image and put in my div

like this

```
            //CREATE A CANVAS ELEMENT
        $("#palco").html("<canvas width='"+largura+"'  height='"+altura+"' id='canvas_zoom'  >");
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_zoom');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        //CREAT AND DRAWN AN IMAGE
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = src_img;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        //DRAW WHATEVER I WANT
        //GER POSITONS LINES Y
        $("#recortar_selecoes").find(".changeliney").each(function () {
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 11, 211, 0.40)";//cor do preenchimento
            ctx.fillRect((parseInt($(this).val()) - 15), 0, 15, altura);//background
        })
        //GER POSITONS LINES X
        $("#recortar_selecoes").find(".changelinex").each(function () {
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(21, 252, 255, 0.40)";//cor do preenchimento
            ctx.fillRect(0, (parseInt($(this).val()) - 15), largura, 15);//background
        })
        ctx.closePath();

        //NOW HERE I WANT TO APPEND AN IMAGE IN DIV ID #palco
        $("#palco").html("???????????????")
```

what should I do in "???????????"

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
   var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        $("#palco").html("<image width='"+largura+"'  height='"+altura+"' id='zoom'  src='"+dataURL+"'   >");
```